# The method parseJson(String) is undefined for the type Util - Facebook SDK error

Tags: android, facebook

The code below is generating the above error.  What is a better way to extract the email address?

```
// process the response here: executed in background thread
Log.d("Facebook-Example", "Response: " + response.toString());
JSONObject json;
try {
    json = Util.parseJson(response);
    fbemail = json.getString("email");
} catch (FacebookError e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Unless you implemented your own Util class, there is no parseJson in 'android.util'. Otherwise post your own Util class

Comment: No i didn't implement my own Util class at all.  Does the error also have something to do with this?  (sorry, very new to programming here) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Util/#parseJson(String)

Comment: I see, your Util class should be imported from Facebook, make sure it is not imported from `android.util`.

Comment: Got it. Even if that Facebook Util class is deprecated?

Comment: If it is deprecated, you have to read the documentation to see what replacement is there. Please accept the answer if it fixed your issue.

Comment: thanks, i will accept it.  how do i specifically import a class from com.facebook.android.util?

Comment: `import com.facebook.android.*;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your Util class is imported from `android.util`.

Import that class from `com.facebook.android.util`